# How to write examples in docstrings that pass Travis CI?

Tags: python, documentation, integration-testing

I'm a friend of examples in docstrings and good examples (in my view) include a statement of what the user will see if she executes some lines of code. Sometimes the output are dictionaries, which as well all know are inherently unordered.

```
"""This method prints a dictionary.

Examples
--------
>>> a = dict(x=1, y=2)
>>> a
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
""""
```

I can of course also be `{'x': 1, 'y': 2}`. And because of that, the Travis CI would complain about a "Failed doctest test" with words similar to these:

```
Expected:
    {'y': 2, 'x': 1}
Got:
    {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

I can't tell Travis CI that a dictionary is unordered. How can I write a docstring with examples that include dictionary output such that the docstring test is passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question is essentially about dictionaries in docstrings. My favorite workaround is

```
"""
>>> a = dict(x=1, y=2)
>>> sorted(a.items())
[('x', 1), ('y', 2)]
"""
```

Comment: What about using ordereddict from itertools?

Comment: Nah, another import. This seems like an overkill when you just want to show the functioning of a method/function...

Answer (score 3):

That does sound kind of annoying.

I don't think you can do anything about it beyond raising an issue against Travis CI (because this *is* a Travis bug) and hoping it'll get fixed.

In the meantime, you could configure Travis CI not to run this particular test, or you could adjust the order and pray that the result is at least partially deterministic on your particular installation, given a particular input.

For what it's worth, you're not alone:

- https://github.com/nengo/nengo/issues/809
- https://github.com/nengo/nengo/issues/830

It looks like various projects are having to write workarounds for this problem.

Comment: Ha! *Finally* a use-case for [tag:ruby]'s ordered `Hash`es!

Comment: Yes it's indeed annoying. I reported a bug: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5684 Let's hope they care about, as it's competing with 900 other issues.

Comment: Issue already closed. Tja, we must continue living with that.

Comment: @MERose: Hmm, to be honest, I didn't spot that your function returns a string.

Comment: @MERose: And the docstring describes the expected output of the function. Which, I realised after writing this answer, is a string. If it were an object I'd expect Travis to be cleverer about verifying the test results. But it's not so I no longer agree that it can really be considered a Travis bug. I'm basically saying that I now dispute my own answer. :)

Comment: Alright, it's not a bug, but at least an annoying "feature".

Comment: @MERose: Given the response to the travis issue you submitted, I would ask on a Travis support forum how to write a test for a dictionary return value in a docstring. Maybe then someone will see your problem.

Comment: In what universe could this *possibly* be considered a bug in Travis CI? It's completely unrelated! This is an issue with doctest, and it will be an issue regardless of whether you are running your tests locally or on Travis.